# R data.table Rolling Join when rollends = (FALSE, FALSE)

Tags: r, join, data.table

I am trying to do a rolling join in the data.table package in R close to the example below. I understand that setting rollends to c(FALSE, FALSE) indicates that values falling before the first value or after the last value for a group should not be rolled.

However, it is unclear to me why the last value itself is not being included in the output of the example below, that is, why does 2018-05-31 have a value of NA instead of 1.5 in the example below. I understand that the value of 2018-06-30 is NA, as the last value should not be rolled forward.

Is the below desired behavior of rollends? I would have expected the last value to not be rolled forward but still included in the rolling join.

```
tableB <- data.table(DT = c("2018-01-31", "2018-02-28", "2018-03-30", "2018-04-30", "2018-05-31", "2018-06-30"))
tableA <- data.table(DT = c("2018-02-23", "2018-05-09"),
                 value = c(0.5, 1.5))
tableB[, DT := as.Date(DT)]
tableA[, DT := as.Date(DT)]
setkey(tableA, DT)
setkey(tableB, DT)
tableA[, .SD[tableB, roll = Inf, on = "DT", rollends = c(FALSE, FALSE)]]

#            DT value
# 1: 2018-01-31    NA
# 2: 2018-02-28   0.5
# 3: 2018-03-30   0.5
# 4: 2018-04-30   0.5
# 5: 2018-05-31    NA
# 6: 2018-06-30    NA
```

### rollends Help [1]

> **rollends** A logical vector length 2 (a single logical is recycled) indicating whether values falling before the first value or after the last value for a group should be rolled as well.
>
> • If rollends[2]=TRUE, it will roll the last value forward. TRUE by default
>   for LOCF and FALSE for NOCB rolls.
>
> • If rollends[1]=TRUE, it will roll the first value backward. TRUE by default
>   for NOCB and FALSE for LOCF rolls.
>   When roll is a finite number, that limit is also applied when rolling the ends.

### sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.7.4   RollingWindow_0.2 devtools_1.13.5   xlsx_0.5.7        xlsxjars_0.6.1    openxlsx_4.0.17   stringr_1.3.0    
[8] data.table_1.11.2 RJDBC_0.2-7.1     rJava_0.9-9       DBI_1.0.0        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.17   digest_0.6.15  withr_2.1.2    R6_2.2.2       git2r_0.21.0   magrittr_1.5   httr_1.3.1     stringi_1.1.7  curl_3.2      
[10] tools_3.5.0    compiler_3.5.0 memoise_1.1.0
```

[1] https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf

[2] https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2933

Comment: It is clear that the value should not be rolled forward, but it is not included in the output at all. I would have assumed that not rolling a value forward means including the value, but not filling up subsequent entries with the value.